# SQLi Error when trying to echo a certain ID in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a status update page for practicing PHP and MySQL.

I am currently trying to echo the saved status on the page.

The statuses are saved in a row called "Status" and they are all given a certain ID in a row called "statusID."

The problem I am having is which fetch I want to use because converting it into a string using `(string)$var` doesn't work. (`$var` is an example).

Also, the `$idNum` variable is something for later use, shouldn't have anything to do with this.

Here is the code: (Obviously the first variables are censored so none tries to connect to the database, the connection working in the actual code.)
The problem lies in the `$fetchRes` I believe.

```
<?php
$idNum = 1;
$servername = "censored";
$username = "censored";
$password = "censored";
$db_name = "censored";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Status FROM SavedStatuses WHERE statusID=1;";
$statusQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$fetchRes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statusQuery);

if($conn->query($sql) == TRUE)
{
    echo $fetchRes;
} else {
    echo "Failed to retrieve status, error: " . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

Comment: you're querying twice, query once and loop over successful results

Comment: `mysqli_query`, `$conn->query`. Make sure you understand which mysqli approach you use.

Comment: Could you post an answer? I'm pretty new to this so I'm not even sure where the second query is occuring

Comment: Read this http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp hope your problem is solved

Comment: What response  are you got?

Comment: reading the official manuals and following the examples would have helped

Comment: I've read a lot and written down notes, but I hate how most tutorials don't really apply to acutally doing it and how solving this sort of problem works, therefor I like trying things out and searching for problems and if I dont find a solution I ask here

Comment: again; read the "official" manuals http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php and you'll get your solution. There are ample tutorials also.

Comment: @Chaost I posted something for you below to help you out.

Comment: *"Could you post an answer?"* - [and so I did...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41764499/1415724) @Chaost or did you leave the question or figured it out for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you are querying twice and not looping over (successful) results.

A "loop" is to use either a `while` or a `foreach`. I used a `while` loop for this example.

From the "official" manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Example:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

So in your case, your code would read as:

**Sidenote:** `Status` and `status` are two different animals, so make sure the letter case matches (in the loop).

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("censored", "censored", "censored", "censored");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Status FROM SavedStatuses WHERE statusID=1";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["Status"];
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}else{
echo "The query failed: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);

}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the answer, haven't had the opportunity to reply until now. This definitely worked so I am gonna read up on how it works now! Thanks a lot